# Find PDF of the random variable Y. Please help!

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent and identically distributed Uniform $(0,1)$ random variables. Let $Y = \max(X_1, X_2)$. Find the PDF of the random variable $Y$.

I am having a hard time progressing with this problem. Would I first begin with $Fy = P(\max(X_1, X_2) \le z)$, and then take the derivative?

Comment: How do you calculate $P(\max(X_1,X_2)<z)$, when $X_1,X_2$ are independent ? Note that
 $$\max(X_1,X_2)<z \:\equiv\: X_1\le z \wedge X_2\le z$$

Comment: Wouldn't it just be P(X1<z)*P(X2<z) ?

Comment: Exactly, just becasue they're independent, And now you're finished ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $Y \in (0, b)$ (for $b \in [0, 1]$), then we know that both $X_1 \in (0, b)$ *and* $X_2 \in (0, b)$. Then,
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Pr}(Y \leq b) &= \mathrm{Pr}(X_1 \leq b \cap X_2 \leq b) \\
&= \mathrm{Pr}(X_1 \leq b) \cdot \mathrm{Pr}(X_2 \leq b) \tag{by independence} \\
&= (b)(b) \\
\mathrm{Pr}(Y \leq b) &= b^2.
\end{align*}$$
Then we know that the CDF of $Y$ is $b \mapsto b^2$.

Let $f$ be the PDF of $Y$.
Then
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Pr}(Y \leq b) &= \int_{0}^{b} f(y) \, dy \\
b^2 &= \int_{0}^{b} f(y) \, dy \\
f(y) &= 2y. \tag*{$\square$}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

$P(Y < t) = P (\max(X_1, X_2) < t) = P (X_1 < t ~\wedge X_2 < t) =  P(X_1<t)P(X_2<t) $ by independence. Calculate this cumulative distribution function and it should be easy to find the density

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
\begin{align}
Y:\Omega&\longrightarrow \mathbb R\\
\omega&\longmapsto \max\{X_1(\omega),X_2(\omega)\}
\end{align}
Then $F_Y(y):=\mathbb P(Y\leq y) =\mathbb P(\max\{X_1,X_2\}\leq y) =\mathbb P(X_1\leq y, X_2 \leq y)$. If they are independent then
$$F_Y(y)=\mathbb P(X_1\leq y)·\mathbb P(X_2\leq y) = F_{X_1}(y)·F_{X_2}(y).$$